# How to partially apply Link or a tag in React?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to deactivate Link in children container like this.

```
<Link to="/somewhere">
<div>
activate Link

<div>
deactivate Link
</div>

activate Link
</div>
</Link>
```

Is that possible?

More specifically, I have radio buttons inside the container. Everytime I click the button, page changes. I want to fix it not to change the page when I push the button.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please improve your question with more code and data of what you are trying to do. Would help!

Comment: You could use some state and conditionally render the link whenever you want it to be active. It wouldn't make for a good user experience if you rendered a link that doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to create twitter polls like system where you can vote by clicking the button and also you can see the detail of the tweet when you click the outside of the button. I thought that could be achieved by changing the Link condition in the children container.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [linkActivated, setLinkActivated] = useState(true)

const handleClick = e => {
 e.preventDefault()
 if(linkActivated)
 {
  setLinkActivated(false)
 } else {
  setActivated(true)
 }
}

<Link onClick={handleClick}>
<div>
activate Link

<div>
deactivate Link
</div>

activate Link
</div>
</Link>
```

Doing so it's a problem, beceause you will never travel to the route. Beceause on every click you activate and deactivate.

What you could do is this:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
const MyComponent = () => {

const [linkActivated, setLinkActivated] = useState(true)
const history = useHistory();

const handleLinkClick = e => {
 e.preventDefault();
 if(linkActivated){
  // travel to link
 history.push("/somehwere");
 }

}
 return (
  <Link onClick={handleLinkClick}>My Link</Link>
  <button onClick={setLinkActivated(!linkActivated)}>
   {linkActivated ? 'Deactivate link' : 'Activate link'}
  </button> 
 )
}
```

Since it's been a while i haven't touch react, if the line  below doesn't work try the second one

```
<Link onClick={handleLinkClick}>My Link</Link>

//if doens't work
<Link onClick={e => handleLinkClick(e)}>My Link</Link>

//or
<Link onClick={e => e.preventDefault();handleLinkClick }>My Link</Link>
//and remove the e parameter in method and aswell the e.preventDefault
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your `<Link>` inside a custom HOC and render it conditionally, like so:

```
const LinkHOC = (props) => {
    if (props.active) return (
        <Link to={props.to}>{props.text}</Link>
    );

    return (
        <span>{props.text></span>
    );
}
```

and use it like this: `<LinkHOC to='/path' text='Redirect' active={true} /}`